# Extracting the data based on the values

Tags: r, dplyr, sqldf

I have a data frame like below, where the error 1 is present if there is a error in DOB and after that the corrected  DOB for the same record with no error. I want to extract only the data which are not corrected and having the error 1. Could anyone out there help me on this.

```
ID  Date1          Date2     DOB       Code Error
381 2002-10-01  2015-10-01  1967-01-22  4   1
381 2002-10-01  2015-10-01  1967-01-20  4   NA
381 2011-10-01  2015-10-01  1969-05-13  11  1
381 2011-10-01  2015-10-01  1968-05-13  11  NA
837 2005-12-07  2015-12-07  1987-11-19  8   1
837 2005-12-08  2015-12-08  1989-12-07  8   1
837 2001-04-15  2015-04-15  1984-08-11  18  1
840 2001-04-23  2015-04-23  1999-03-14  18  NA
```

The output table will have the details below.

```
ID  Date1          Date2      DOB      Code Error
837 2005-12-07  2015-12-07  1987-11-19  8   1
837 2005-12-08  2015-12-08  1989-12-07  8   1
837 2001-04-15  2015-04-15  1984-08-11  18  1
```

Comment: `df %>% group_by(ID) %>% filter(all(Error) == 1)` ?

Comment: `df[which(df$Error == 1), ]`

Comment: @Sotos ..Thank you so much.It is working with this reproduced example but unfortunately when i used this method to my original data, i am not getting the records.Don't know where it is going wrong.

Comment: @ssan, the code selects IDs which do not contain NA at all. Is that right?

Comment: @Sotos, you are right. I think the error column is the problem. In my original data i have 354 as error instead 1. so I replaced the 1 in your code with 354.